# How to SUMIF (or ??) using criteria from another function value return?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to do a very simple sum of a column that excludes the colored ones.  The column I wish to sum is all my accounts and the green ones represent the paid accounts.  I want a sum that represents the "left to pay" value to keep track of my progress without redoing my formula every time.  The color is not conditional, nor can it be.

I have 2 functions created already:

```
Function GetColor(MyCell As Range)
GetColor = MyCell.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

and

```
Function PAID(MyCell As Range) As Boolean
    If MyCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 50 Then
        PAID = True
    Else
        PAID = False
    End If
End Function
```

So I have already created one column next to my numbers that have the formula (with changing cell number):

```
=PAID(C13)
```

and this spits out TRUE or FALSE values that I can then based my SUMIF formula off of, currently I have this (E column containing values from the PAID function, C contains my account values):

```
=SUMIF(E2:E18,"FALSE",C2:C18)
```

I would like to see if it's possible to bypass making this extra column and run the function directly in the SUMIF (or maybe another function?) so that all I have to do is color my cell and refresh only one formula.

Comment: This is rather complex and open to errors to rely on hard colour-coding - why dont you enter in a simple "paid" against the paid items?

Comment: I realize using the ColorIndex is not ideal but it did the job for a simple task such as a sum.  Also I am challenged frequently in Python, XML, and VB despite not being a programmer and hating coding, so this keeps my brain active on that front.  It's a neat idea for this spreadsheet anyhow and simpler than I thought to get as far as I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using colours as part of the program decision process is not ideal, and is overly complex for a simple task.

But assuming you want this (or have no control over this), and the cells you want to sum are **NOT** coloured with `Interior.ColorIndex = 50` - and assuming your values are in range `C2:C18` (or wherever), a VBA function to do this is below.

Use the function as `=PAID(C2:C18,50)`

```
Function PAID(MyCells As Range, colour_avoid As Integer) As Double
Dim cc As Range
Dim accumulate As Double

accumulate = 0 'not needed but good practice

  For Each cc In MyCells
    If (cc.Interior.ColorIndex <> colour_avoid) Then
       accumulate = accumulate + cc.Value
    End If
  Next cc
PAID = accumulate
End Function
```

To repeat, this function will sum all the cells **NOT** coloured with a `colour.index` that you give to it (say, 50).

Comment: Thanks!  That was it!  Although the formula added up all the color ones, rather than excluding.  So I changed the color code to reflect the color of the other cells (in this case a light gray 15) and it was perfect!  THANKS!!!!

Comment: @user3161018 Sorry - yes, I missed you saying you were doing `SUMIF` on the `FALSES`. It is easy to change - I will update the question with an alternative version that sums if the colour index is **NOT** some given number.

Comment: @user3161018 updated the function to perform as you originally described it. It now should sum the cells **NOT** coloured with a `colour.Index` that you give to it.